# pyvenv still broken on 14.04.1?

Tags: 14.04, python, python3

```
meow@te:~# pyvenv-3.4 v
Error: Command '['/meow/v/bin/python3.4', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I thought it was fixed. I've done update and upgrade, did reboot after updating all the latest fixes since release. I still hit this problem.

Thoughts?
[pyvenv-3.4 error: returned non-zero exit status 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

Comment: At this point it's just way easier to download the source, build, and install it myself

Comment: Still broken, discussion here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847

Comment: possible duplicate of [pyvenv-3.4 error: returned non-zero exit status 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, still broken on Ubuntu 14.04, as I mentioned in [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/528625/). You can see the [Ubuntu bug 1290847](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847).

See [my Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/21e50a357f2d4920091e) for more details and more links.