# pyvenv-3.4 disappeared in Ubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: 14.04, python, python3, virtualenv

This is what I was doing to create a venv in Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS until last week:

```
» pyvenv-3.4 --without-pip venv
```

I was doing that because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/488530/23493). But since yesterday:

```
» pyvenv-3.4 --without-pip venv
The program 'pyvenv-3.4' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

python3.4 is **definitely** installed:

```
» python3.4 --version
Python 3.4.3
```

I have probably done an apt-upgrade recently, but ... why has `pyvenv-3.4` disappeared?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -L python3.4 | grep pyvenv-3.4` and `apt-cache policy  python3.4`

Comment: Something strange happened to `python3.4` in the last update cycle.  It now appears in Synaptic Package Manager under "installed - local or obsolete" along with all its dependencies.  In fact, I think this is worth its own question.

Answer (score 8):

`venv` is a built-in module in Python 3. You can always call it via the `-m <module>` call stack. So for your example:

```
python3 -m venv --without-pip venv
```

---

As for where it's gone, `3.4.0` (in `trusty-updates` and `trusty-security`) ships the script. However 3.4.3 in `trusty-proposed` does not. This may explain why yours has gone missing.

You can still use it with `python3 -m venv ...` so it's not that important.

---

If you're wondering how you ended up on `3.4.3`, it was SRUd into `trusty-updates` back in September and pulled very recently after it was [found to break several things](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1500768). This should be fixed and re-released in short order. Follow that bug report for updates.

Comment: The file should be in the package python3.4, see here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pyvenv-3.4&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

Comment: A `dpkg -L python3.4 | grep venv` on my system doesn't show it in the file listing. That suggests that it's been removed in later versions. I'm on 3.4.3-1ubuntu1 from trusty-proposed.