# How to update virtualenv from Python 3.5 to 3.6 on AWS with requirement.txt?

Tags: python, pip, aws

I am having [a trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408122/how-to-send-image-in-base-64-hex-string-with-json-stringify) to deploy my Django project due to Python version differences, so I want to update its version on AWS (16.04.4).

I currently have a virtual environment with Python 3.5, so I am trying to create the new one with Python 3.6. So far, I did:

```
$ source oldenv/bin/activate
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ deactivate
$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
$ python3.6 -m venv newenv
```

And, I got an error:

> '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero
>   exit status 1.

I looked at [the similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1), and [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847) that 14.04 shipped with a broken pyvenv seemed to be already fixed.

Some answers recommend using without-pip, but I want to recover packages by

```
$ newenv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So, it does not sound like a good idea. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the first approach does not work, but here is a work-around:

```
$ pip install virtualenv --user
$ virtualenv -p python3.6 newenv
$ newenv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```